# Parallelize the processes to gain speed

Tags: bash

I have a expect script that I use to collect interfaces on switches cisco. And I have a bash script that makes a loop. The input file was divided in 8 parts (sw_aa to sw_ah with 6 lines each one).

```
sw_aa
169.254.253.2,169.254.253.1,169.254.253.1,sw_aa
...

sw_ab
169.254.254.2,169.254.254.1,169.254.254.1,sw_ab
...

etc...


loop.sh  
#!/bin/bash
SW=( $(cut -d "," -f 1 sw_??) )
RT=( $(cut -d "," -f 2 sw_??) )
Pre=( $(cut -d "," -f 3 sw_??) )
lote=( $(cut -d "," -f 4 sw_??) )

for((i=0;i<${#SW[@]};i++)); do
 ./ciscoswitches.sh "${SW[$i]} ${RT[$i]} ${Pre[$i]} ${lote[$i]}" >> ${SW[$i]}.log
done
```

I need parallelize the processes to gain speed, so I can attack the first line of each input file and then follow the loop untill the end. How I can make this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use GNU Parallel. Prefix the second to last line with `echo`, i.e. `echo ./ciscoswitches.sh ...` and add `| parallel` to the very last line.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, great answer! Simple and easy to read. I did some tests and I got the results in just 2 minutes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it works for you. It's late so I'll write it up as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do, but in general, you can parallelise a loop using **GNU Parallel** by generating a list of commands you need done in parallel and sending them to **GNU Parallel's** standard input stream:

```
for((i=0;i<${#SW[@]};i++)); do
  echo ./ciscoswitches.sh ...
done | parallel
```

You may want to look at adding `-j 8` for example if you want to run 8 parallel processes rather than the standard of 1 process per CPU core. Also, maybe the `-k` switch` to keep the output in order. You can also tag the output of each process.